# Design pattern for reading information from local json on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, json, design-patterns, singleton

I have a local json file named "list.json" in my Xcode and I will read this file to show my information in UITableView, I want to use design pattern for this implementation, Like Singleton pattern, would you please give me hint that is it good to used Singleton or not and how can I re-implement this method?

Thanks in advance!

here is the way that I read may json:

```
-(void)readDataFromFile
{
    NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError * error;
    NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    self.data = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self readDataFromFile];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: "I want to use design pattern". No. You learn designs patterns, and learn to apply them when necessary. Not because "using design patterns is good". In your case, you don't need a design pattern, [even](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/) [less](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx) [a Singleton](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid).

Comment: At the point where you do [self readDataFromFile] you have your data in a readable format, so you can simply access the particular object within the JSON in cellForRowAtIndexPath to display what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When we speak of design pattern, it should be kept in mind that we should not insist a design pattern to fit in a scenario. Rather we should choose a particular design pattern based on the scenario.

And it is also important to know that design patterns are by-product of some renowned tools which are:

- design principles
- removing code smells through refactoring

Keeping these in mind, you may think of an interface `IReader` for your scenario which may have a `Read()` method that takes a filename as input and return a list of objects. A class `JsonReader` may implement the `Read()` method of `IReader`.

Now you need to put the information collected from Json to a control like `UITableView`. Here instead of making the `UITableView` tightly coupled to Json, you may consider another interface `IBinder` that may have a method taking an instance of `IReader` and another instance of `ITable` and binds the data to the ITable. The later interface is implemented by some other class say `UITableViewController` which takes an instance of `UITableView` in its constructor. `UITableViewController` class will provide the mechanisms to access the outlets and actions of `UITableView`.